# Clone command help needed

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

For a new command block creation, I've got the idea for a constant test for a bat, so when it's spawned, it'll die instantly, and the `/clone` command will clone a house from a location to near the player. The thing is, I don't know how to make the `/clone` command paste in the house near the player, as `~# ~# ~#` works using it in a command, but a command in a command block doesn't work.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you please give us the specific commands you are using? Right now we won't be able to help you at all because it's a bit unclear what you are doing.

Comment: A recent edit changed the whole question with the justification "to fit my needs", doesn't this conflict with the autor intent?

Comment: @pinckerman I was kinda skeptical about this too. That's why I did cast a reopen vote to let people judge about FIRE_of_ETERNITY edit. Else, and most probably, we can just rollback to the [original question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/250156/2).

Comment: @Isuka Considering that the original question has an answer (which was accepted) probably a rollback is a good solution. But I think that the question can be reopened anyway.

Comment: @pinckerman Seems like the best option there. Rollback done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relative coordinates (`~#`) are relative to the thing that's executing the command. As an example,  if `~ ~5 ~` is in a command block, it will target 5 blocks above the command block.

To have the command in a command block, but have the coordinates relative to a player, you should use the `/execute` command. The syntax of it is:

```
/execute <entity> <x> <y> <z> <command …>
```

So, for your problem, you'll likely want to do something like this:

```
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ /clone <X1> <Y1> <Z1> <X2> <Y2> <Z2> ~# ~# ~#
```

Replacing `<X1>`, `<Y1>`, etc. with the original coordinates of the house, and the `#`'s with the offset you want it to be cloned to relative to the player (`@p`).